# How do I align "subject to..." with the minimize word on top

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

[image]

[image]

How do I align "subject to..." with the minimize word on top.

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx Please help us help you and add a https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228 that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Embedding an `aligned` environment inside the `align*` environment gets the job done:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\text{minimize } \sum_{i=1}^k y_i \\
&\text{subject to the modified constraints} \\
&\qquad\qquad
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{x} &\ge 0 \\
s_i &\ge 0 \text{ for slack and surplus variables}\\
y_i &\ge 0 \text{ for artificial variables}
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have not understood any negative score and your off-topic to the my question [on-hold].

Comment: @Sebastiano - I would agree with the notion that the OP's posting could be phrased more clearly. I interpreted (rephrased!) his/her question as follows: "How do I align 'subject to' with the word 'minimize' in the prior line]?" While we're on the subject of interpretation: Where did the term `\frac{a_i}{1+x}` in your answer come from?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[{\scriptscriptstyle\text{minimize}} \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{a_i}{1+x}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the point may be of placing the word "minimize" in the upper limit of summation. Please elaborate.

Comment: Done! I have edited my answer. Thank for your suggestion. :-) Hi, from Sicily.

Comment: How does this relate to the question?

Comment: I have undestood that the OP wanted, in math-mode, to write the smallest word `minimize`. Is this the reason for my bad reputation for the answer? I do not care about the score that I take (in fact I do not ever vote a negative question, rather I encourage users). Very often, and I've always written it, because of my bad English I do not understand what the operator wants.

Comment: @Sebastiano - FWIW, I upvoted your answer...

Comment: @Mico What is FWIW? :-) I have not understood.

Comment: @Sebastiano - "For what it's worth"

Answer (score 0):

With a tabular?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{llcl}
        minimize & \multicolumn{3}{l}{$\sum_{i=1}^{k} y_i$}\\
        \multicolumn{4}{l}{subject to Modified Constraints}\\
        & $x$ & $\geq$ & $0$\\
        & $s_i$ & $\geq$ & $0$ for slack\ldots\\
        & $y_i$ & $\geq$ & $0$ for\ldots
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add an image of the result as well as a small explanation.

Comment: Since the material occurs in math mode, it would probably be better to use an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment. For sure, it would cut down on the number of `$` symbols that will otherwise have to be typed.

Comment: @Mico you answer is far better!